# 100vh doesn't take whole screen

Tags: css

I want to create a one-scroll-page, like each section is full height from screen.

But when I use 100vh, it doesn't take whole screen height, but more like 95%.

Comment: Unrelated to question did you on your own come up with whole theme and  content if yes I am blown away awesome work.And its taking up whole size of myscreen working fine which browser are you facing issue

Comment: try add `body { margin : 0 }`

Comment: @SachinDivakar my friend created the design, I send him a screen of your comment haha. 

Forgot to mention the first section shows 100% perfectly fine. But 2nd etc. doesn't.

MarkoCen Tried your solution but didn't work.

Comment: @C.Ronaldo I want to know in which browser which version you are having this issue I have tested it chrome firefox ie11 in all those it works fine so be specific about in which browser and which version.And Do tell your friend I appreciate the work I rarely find something very appealing like this

Comment: @SachinDivakar Sorry forgot to say, I use Chrome and on my mobile phone (chrome too) it also shows the problem.

Comment: works great for me too on Chrome 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit) on Linux

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding the code below to your CSS should fix it:

```
html,body{
margin:0;
}
```

This is caused by the default margin being `8px` so redefining it using CSS will correct it.

**Illustration with margin Set:**

```css
#Orange{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:orange;
}
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Orange"></div>
```

**Without the `margin:0` adjustment:**

```css
#Orange{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background:orange;
}
body{
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="Orange"></div>
```

### EDIT

Adding this code should adjust the margins for your container.

```
.container-fluid{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But it didn't changed anything.

Comment: Edited it view it the difference is shown

Comment: Hi, sorry for was eating. I put the code inside the section div's, but no changes. Actually a bit change, the extra gap is smaller now, but still not 100%.

Comment: No nO you shouldnt put code inside sections div margin :0 should be set to the body tag the outmost tag can you tell me which chrome version

Comment: Ah yes sorry I meant I have put width: 100vw inside it but margin, padding: 0 in html,body.

I have version: Versie 50.0.2661.102 m

Comment: 50.0.2661.94 m  is my browser version in it its appearing correctly let me update to new version

Comment: Add margin zero and padding 0 to your container class and nav

Comment: Have you noticed horizontal scroll bar appearing now ? header tag have width 1903 and following section tags has 1920 in my browser

Comment: Ah your right, it was caused by 100vw, I changed it back.

Other people also tell me that it's 100%, very strange cause in Firefox I also got 95% and phone too. 

I'm going to give you answer anyway, for the effort. Thanks dude.

Oh yes, the header shows perfectly for me but the rest don't. The strange thing is, they all are 1270 height so all should be the same.

Comment: Dare I say, maybe, `*,*:before,*:after ( margin: 0, padding: 0, box-sizing: border-box; }`

Comment: @C.Ronaldo I appreciate it that you appreciate my effort but I insist you wait for answer which suits you and the margin for to be solved you have to work your way from outside to inside or vice versa and set margin and padding to your wrappers and object because which is causing that issue can only be found out so

Comment: @zer00ne its worth the try

Comment: @zer00ne do you mean *:before, *:after. sorry kinda confused.

SachinDivakar, Thanks I'm gonna try some things

Comment: @C.Ronaldo Also `body { position:relative; line-height: 1; }`  might  be helpful...

Comment: Ah found out what was the issue since you are using that bootstrap row class it tends to do that for solving that issue you just have to create class for adding to all row divs called no-margin.This is one of the issues I encounter while using bootstrap.Usually there is clearfix for that

Comment: @C.Ronaldo Actually, it's that specific see: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#article-header-id-5

Comment: @SachinDivakar Mazel tov +1

Comment: I added no-margin class to all rows and gave it margin:0; but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @C.Ronaldo Dont First of try to undertand the issue bro if you uncheck overflow hidden property you will that block have different width so the many cases the width exceeds other elements.So adjust margins from inside you have to go through it debug section by section it would take time

Comment: Ah yes forgot to update my scss, but the width problem is already fixed.

Comment: Its now rendering correctly for me

Comment: It's really strange cause the first section it shows 1270px height and shows fullscreen, but 2nd section it shows 1270px also but it's not full-screen

Comment: Second screen also shows fullscreen to me you need to closely watch it maximum thing you can do is to set min-height:100vh; which I think you have already done ?

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna ask my teacher tomorrow, perhaps he can tell me what's wrong. I'll let you know when I find out more. THanks for the help! Also zer00

Comment: @C.Ronaldo Do that and get back to me

Comment: @SachinDivakar Hello, it seems it was 100% all the time, but I didn't scroll precisely which caused the small space. Because of the Nav bar it was hard too see. TL;DR I'am just super blind... Sorry for taking your time and thanks. PS: Super embarassed right now.

Comment: @C.Ronaldo Okay no problem happy to help always :D and one other thing there is nothing to embarrassed about it happens to all people trust me there are some little mistakes that no one spots it till some one points to you so its better to find third persons opinion and if you can find all your faults your own then I would say that person is gifted