# why this component height is not full?

Tags: reactjs

[image]

This is my cart component code. I am using styled components.

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { remove } from "../../features/cartSlice";

const Cart = () => {
  const pizzaProducts = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(pizzaProducts);

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    dispatch(remove(id));
  };

  return (
    <CartContainer>
      <CartHeading>Your cart</CartHeading>

      <CartWrapper>
        {pizzaProducts.map((pizzaProduct, index) => {
          return (
            <CartCard key={index}>
              <CartImg src={pizzaProduct.img} alt="err" />
              <CartInfo>
                <CartTitle>{pizzaProduct.name}</CartTitle>
                <CartDescription>{pizzaProduct.desc}</CartDescription>
                <CartPrice>{pizzaProduct.price}</CartPrice>
                <CartButton
                  id="btn"
                  onClick={() => handleRemove(pizzaProduct.id)}
                >
                  Remove
                </CartButton>
              </CartInfo>
            </CartCard>
          );
        })}
      </CartWrapper>
    </CartContainer>
  );
};

const CartContainer = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vh;
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    width: 100%;
  }
`;

const CartHeading = styled.h2`
  height: 40px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-size: clamp(2rem, 2.5vw, 3rem);
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;

const CartWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px 0;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const CartCard = styled.div`
  margin: 0 3rem;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  line-height: 2;
`;

const CartImg = styled.img`
  height: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px #fdc500;
`;

const CartInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
`;

const CartTitle = styled.h2`
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: white;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
`;
const CartDescription = styled.p`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
`;

const CartPrice = styled.p`
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  word-spacing: 1px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
`;
const CartButton = styled.button`
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem 4rem;
  border: none;
  background: #e31837;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.2 ease-out;
  &:hover {
    background: #ffc500;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
  }
`;

export default Cart;
```

I am expecting the full height 100%.

Comment: You seem to have wrapped every single line of your question in `\``, please edit it and make use of the preview section to make sure it's readable.

Comment: Did you try a `height: 100%` on the `CartWrapper`?

Comment: You're setting `height: 100vh` - Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191672/100vh-doesnt-take-whole-screen